# How do I set up gaeunit 2.0a with my Django app?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I am trying to set up Google App Engine unit testing for my web application.  I downloaded the file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/downloads/detail?name=gaeunit-2.0a_for_django.zip).

I followed the instructions in the readmen by copying the directory gaeunit into the directory with the rest of my apps and registering 'gaeunit' in settings.py.  This didn't seem sufficient to actually get things going.  I also stuck `url('^test(.*)', include('gaeunit.urls'))` into my urls.py file.

When I go to the url `http://localhost:8000/test`, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../gaeunit/test'
```

Any suggestions?  I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy url but in your urls.py include

```
(r'^test', include('gaeunit.urls')),
```

Also you will have to change test path in gaeunit.py

```
_LOCAL_DJANGO_TEST_DIR = 'test'
```

And in your main web test files under test folder include following line for django test setup

```
self.application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions on the [main page](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/) you should add the URL to app.yaml, not urls.py.

```
- url: /test.*
  script: gaeunit.py
```

Comment: I'm trying to set it up as a Django app, but I've tried both ways.  This method returns the same error.